# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un slider con videos e imágenes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando realizar un slider que contenga videos e imagenes, hasta ahora puedo reproducir el video y una vez que termine, continue con las imagenes, pero al terminar las imagenes, el video pasa al mismo intervalo de las imagenes.
Como puedo reproducir el video, que termine, que pasen las imagenes y luego volver a reproducir el video? agradezco sus respuestas :D

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imgItems = $('.slider li').length; // NUMERO DE SLIDES
var imgPos = 1;
var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.addEventListener('ended', Slider, false);

function Slider(){
    setInterval(nextSlider, 1000);
}

function nextSlider(){
    if(imgPos >= imgItems){
        imgPos = 1;
    }else{
        imgPos++;
    }

    $('.slider li').hide(); // OCULTAMOS TODOS LOS SLIDES
    $('.slider li:nth-child('+ imgPos +')').fadeIn(1000); // MOSTRAMOS SLIDE SELECCIONADO
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<main class="main">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <ul class="slider">
            <li>
                <video id="video" class="video1" autoplay muted>
                    <source src="assets/videos/fail.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="uploads/images/1.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="uploads/images/2.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en la funciona Slider, primero te corre el vídeo despues pasan las imágenes cada 1segundo pero cuando termina y vuelve al principio el vídeo te tarda 1segundo ya que ne la función nextSlider lo pones en posición 1 y llamas a Slider con un segundo.

Deverias de hacer esto.

```
function Slider(){
    if(imgPos == 1){
        setInterval(nextSlider, duracionvideo);
    }else{
        setInterval(nextSlider, 1000);
    }
}
```

Hay que detectar la posición del slider para cambiarle el delay de la llamada a la función para cambiar de item.